# GraphQL Interface calling error in rails 7

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, graphql

Need to use GraphQL Interface for showing some common fields of the object, I have created a Customer model with its attributes **name** and **age**. also created customer type in Graphql.

**app/graphql/types/customer_type.rb**

```
module Types
  class CustomerType < Types::BaseObject
    field :id, ID, null: false
    field :name, String
    field :age, String
    field :created_at, GraphQL::Types::ISO8601DateTime, null: false
    field :updated_at, GraphQL::Types::ISO8601DateTime, null: false
  end
end
```

Create a customer interface inside -

**app/graphql/types/customer_interface_type.rb**

```
module Types
  module CustomerInterfaceType
    include Types::BaseInterface
    field :id, ID, null: false
  end
end
```

Implement the above interface in object type -

**app/graphql/types/customer_interface.rb**

```
module Types 
    class CustomerInterface < Types::BaseObject
        implements Types::CustomerInterfaceType
        field :name, String, null: false
    end
end
```

add customers field in query_type.rb file.
**app/graphql/types/query_type.rb**

```
module Types
  class QueryType < Types::BaseObject
    include GraphQL::Types::Relay::HasNodeField
    include GraphQL::Types::Relay::HasNodesField

    field :customers, [Types::CustomerInterfaceType], null: false

    def customers
        Customer.all.order(id: :desc)
    end

  end
end
```

front-end query

```
query {
  customers {
    id
    name
  }
}
```

getting can't query field "customers" on type query.
I am a beginner in GraphQL don't why getting this error.